# Passing Column name as string in mysql Insert query

Tags: c#, mysql

this is what i am trying to do after receiving string from the serial port. i get whitespace between the data so i put two loops to eliminate them. i want to recieve data spanning multiple columns and a single row for every single run of do while loop.. Thanks in Advance

```
string text = sp.readline();




for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; )
 {
     p = text[i].ToString();
     if (p != " ")
     {
     do
        {
         x += text[i].ToString();
         s = text[i].ToString();
         i++;
         } while (s != " ");
         try
           {
              string col = "column" + no.ToString();
              MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
              cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO testdata("+col+")VALUES(?data)";
              cmd.Parameters.Add("?data", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = x;
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              x = "";
              p = "";
              no++;
           }
         catch (Exception ex)
           {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           }


     } i++;

}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say, you cannot, in any dialect of SQL, provide a table or column name as a bindable variable (or parameter). If it's working for MySQL that's terrific, but if you change over to any other DBMS make and model, it will suddenly stop working.

Also, `INSERT` *means* create a new row. You'll either need to insert all the column values at once in a single `INSERT` statement, or figure out how to `INSERT` one row and then `UPDATE` it for each new column value.

Comment: Thanks Ollie. i guess i have to find a way to alter table on a matching criteria with the first column's value this loop insert. Thanks again.

Comment: and i guess that also is not the right approach to do that. so i will figure out something else. :)

Comment: @user3095292: just build the command string with the column names directly. You already have the column name in your `col` variable. Just concatenate that in your `CommandText`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to insert a single row having multiple column, then for loop is not required 
following is for three columns

```
int no = 2;

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO testdata(?col1,?col2,?col3)VALUES(?data1,?data2,?data3)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("?col1", MySqlDbType.String).Value = col1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?col2", MySqlDbType.String).Value = col2;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?col3", MySqlDbType.String).Value = col3;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?data1", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = x1;

cmd.Parameters.Add("?data2", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = x2;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?data3", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = x3;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: i am using 2 loops two loops to remove **" "** at many places in the string received from serial.readline().

Comment: The real change is the uncertainty of the amount of data i receive from this device in at a single instance of serial.readline().